# What happens if there were only ordinary matter in the universe? Would the universe expand constantly? or will it decelerate?

Tags: cosmology

This question hit me when I was watching 'Cosmos by Neil deGrasse Tyson' explaining how the universe is expanding and how it accelerates because of dark energy and dark matter, then I asked myself what if there were only ordinary matter in the universe?

Comment: [It depends on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric#Reduced-circumference_polar_coordinates) the Gaussian curvature $k$, e.g. the expansion is eternal but decelerating if $k=0$, whereas the Universe's size oscillates if $k>0$.

Comment: Duplicated on Astronomy SE. Please delete one of them. Preferably this one since the other has two upvoted answers.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary matter is baryonic matter. From Planck data and other astronomical observations, we know that only about 5% of all the mass-energy in the universe is baryonic matter (which basically consists of hydrogen and helium).

This means that the density parameter associated with baryonic matter is

$$\Omega_b=0.05$$

If we assume that the universe is composed of baryonic matter and nothing else (no dark matter, no dark energy), then the above density is the total density parameter,

$$\Omega_0=0.05$$

Since $\Omega_0<1$, according to the Friedmann equations, the geometry of space is hyperbolic $(K<0)$ and the universe will expand forever. But the expansion will be decelerating due to the mutual gravitational pull of baryonic matter.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of ordinary matter in the universe, is less than 5% of the amount that would be required to ultimately halt the expansion of the universe [(Planck 2018 results)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_(spacecraft)).

Even if you were to add in the "dark matter" this fraction would only creep up to 31.5%.

Thus without dark energy, the fate of the universe would be to expand at a *decelerating* rate, but never coming to a halt. A bit like throwing a ball away from the Earth at greater than the escape speed.

The addition of dark energy means that the expansion is now (and in the future, as far as we know) *accelerating*.